# If Not function proceeds when value *is* the one specified

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a script which checks for duplicate values in another worksheet, but I cannot get it to work. At line `problem` the If function *always* proceeds, whether set to `If Not` or `If`. LocatedCell does equal Nothing.

I am sure this is an obvious error but I cannot understand it.

```
Sub mailer_followuptest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Remove matching contacts data from last run
   Dim wsDel As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsDel = Sheets("Matching Contacts")
    wsDel.Delete

Dim mailerSheet As Worksheet
Set mailerSheet = Worksheets("Call data")

Set MatchingContacts = Sheets.Add
MatchingContacts.Name = "Matching Contacts"

Dim DesiredEntry As String
Dim CRMContacts As Worksheet
Set CRMContacts = Worksheets("CRM contacts")

CRMContacts.Select
Range("A1").Select

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
DesiredEntry = ActiveCell.Value


    With Sheets(mailerSheet).Range("A:A")

        Dim LocatedCell As Range
        Set LocatedCell = .Find(What:=DesiredEntry, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart)



problem: If Not LocatedCell = "Nothing" Then

             'With_
             LocatedCell.EntireRow.Copy_
                 '.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
             'End With

        MatchingContacts.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


        End If

    End With

    CRMContacts.Select

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Additionally, am I using find correctly? It doesn't appear to be working either.

Comment: The way you use `Nothing` is not proper. It should go with `Is` and not the `=` sign. Try this instead `If Not LocatedCell Is Nothing Then` or `If LocatedCell Is Nothing Then`. Also, the way you use `.Find` has many holes. Try adapting to [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx)

Comment: One tip: Using `On Error Resume Next` means telling the code to "Shut UP" and do what you want. In most cases it will do what you want... Shut Up and perform... but then you will not get the expected results. So please use `OERN` judiciously ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Use `On Error Resume Next`  judiciously.

Don't use `On Error Resume Next` for the entire code - it will hide all your errors. Use it only when it's really needed.

Using `On Error Resume Next` means telling the code to `Shut UP` and do what you want. In most cases it will do what you want... Shut Up and perform... but then you will not get the expected results or totally wrong results as shown below !!! *(SiddharthRout ©:)*

[image]

Change

```
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set wsDel = Sheets("Matching Contacts")
wsDel.Delete
```

to

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wsDel = Sheets("Matching Contacts")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wsDel Is Nothing Then wsDel.Delete
```

line `On Error GoTo 0` will return your error handler to default mode.

---

**Some issues with your code:**

**1)** In line `If Not LocatedCell = "Nothing" Then` you tries to identify whether your cells *value* doesn't equal *string* "Nothing" which is uncorrect.

To check whether the `.Find` function returns any cell, change

```
If Not LocatedCell = "Nothing" Then
```

to

```
If Not LocatedCell Is Nothing Then
```

**2)** change `With Sheets(mailerSheet).Range("A:A")` to `With
    mailerSheet.Range("A:A")`

**3)** as @SiddharthRout mentioned in comments below,

> The copy has to be right before the paste special. Excel is very well known for clearing the clipboard if you perform some specific actions

if you are going to change interior color and copy row, change

```
'With_
   LocatedCell.EntireRow.Copy_
   '.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
'End With
```

to

```
With LocatedCell.EntireRow
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
     .Copy
End With
```

**4)** and of course: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: + 1 Esp for the last line. Also I see one more problem. The copy has to be right before the paste special. Excel is very well known for clearing the clipboard if you perform some specific actions. For example `.Interior.ColorIndex` And not to mention the biggest problem of all! Using `On Error Resume Next` recklessly ;)

Comment: Very tempted to add a cartoon to your post which I just created :D

Comment: You can undo the changes if you want to :P

Comment: Thanks, I always wondered how to return to the default error handling.


~ When I set `If Not LocatedCell = Nothing Then` i get "Invalid use of object and it highlights `Nothing` ~


@L42 points out it should be The way you use Nothing is not proper. It should go with Is and not the = sign. Try this instead `If Not LocatedCell Is Nothing Then` or `If LocatedCell Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: You should use `Is` keyword instead `=` sign. *Correct statement:* `If Not LocatedCell Is Nothing Then`. *UNcorrect statement:* `If Not LocatedCell = Nothing Then`

Comment: haha never thought that @SiddharthRout is a cartoonist.LOL :D