# button flickering despite Application.screenupdating = false

Tags: excel, vba

so I tried the solutions here [Excel ScreenUpdating False and still flickering screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721513/excel-screenupdating-false-and-still-flickering-screen) but nth worked , im wondering if I should put the screen update in the fucntion I call
Note that the function i call is gonna call another that'll parse data in the sheet once button 2 is clicked,Here's the code I did so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ButtonOneClick = False
    Call SheetName
    If ButtonOneClick Then
        Me.CommandButton2.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.CommandButton2.Visible = False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @StureS why ? do u thinkk what i asked isnt clear ? too long ?

Comment: @StureS I cant since im calling a function that calls another (it says code too long) plus even if u run it u wont have the sheets that im working with

Comment: try turning screen updating off and on in the sub `SheetName` aswell

Comment: You could hide the button once clicked and when all operations are complete decide if it will be shown or not. Would this work?

Comment: @MGP k I did that in both the subs that are called now the whole excel stopped flickering so its better but the button still does

Comment: @KostasK. Thats exactly what I wanted to (clearly failed) cuz my goal was to make the button disappear once clicked (no need to see it parsing hundreds of lines) but I thought thats how we code it (sorry if the code is naive )

Comment: So, before you start the long operation, set its visibility to false followed by `DoEvents` to action it before the code jumps to the next line (single threaded).

Comment: @KostasK. Amazing !! It worked thanks alot