# Find multiple values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

I want to highlight all accuring values in a excel file. My code however only highlights the first found value for every sheet, but I want to highlight every found value. I guess the ``FindNext'' does not work as i expect it to work. I tried multple other examples from the internet, which show the same result. What is going wrong?

```
Sub test()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim currentSheet As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index

    datatoFind = StrConv(InputBox("Please enter the value to search for"), vbLowerCase)

    If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub

    sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If IsError(CDbl(datatoFind)) = False Then datatoFind = CDbl(datatoFind)
    For counter = 1 To sheetCount
        Sheets(counter).Activate

        Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cell.Address
            Do
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                cell = Cells.FindNext(After:=cell)
            Loop Until cell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: try to change `cell = Cells.FindNext(After:=cell)` to `Set cell = Cells.FindNext(After:=cell)`

Comment: and alos interesting read for you: [Why I should use On Error Resume Next judiciously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673529/if-not-function-proceeds-when-value-is-the-one-specified/21673617#21673617)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As follow up from comments this one works (code slighlty improved):

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim datatoFind
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    datatoFind = StrConv(InputBox("Please enter the value to search for"), vbLowerCase)
    If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(datatoFind) Then datatoFind = CDbl(datatoFind)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Cells
            Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = cell.Address
                Do
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                    If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop Until cell.Address = FirstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Your `Loop Until cell.Address = FirstAddress` triggers an error when `cell` is nothing, that's why I added `If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do` (You don't see this error messages because you're using `On Error Resume Next`)

Also two interesting reads for you:

1. [**Why I should use On Error Resume Next judiciously**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673529/if-not-function-proceeds-when-value-is-the-one-specified/21673617#21673617)
2. [**How to avoid using Select/Active statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)