# Move Under Marco not working when altered to move between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to alter my `move under` macro to move columns under columns on a different sheet.

It worked fine when I was moving columns under other columns on the same sheet.

I can not get the proper syntact for the `wsS.Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lRow, j)).Copy _
       Destination:=wsT.Range(Cells(LR, k), Cells(LR, k)).Offset(1, 0)`

When I run the macro nothing happens no errors are thrown and nothing is moved

Thanks

```
Sub MoveUnder()
Dim wsS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsT As Worksheet
Dim ar As Variant
Dim er As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim h As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim LR As Long


Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set wsT = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    ar = Array("user id", "user name")    ' Find column to copy
    er = Array("user id", "user name")    ' Find column to paste beneith

lRow = wsS.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
LR = wsT.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
    j = wsS.Rows(1).Find(ar(i), Rows(1).Cells(Rows(1).Cells.count), , xlWhole,   xlByRows).Column
    k = wsT.Rows(1).Find(er(i), Rows(1).Cells(Rows(1).Cells.count), , xlWhole, xlByRows).Column

      wsS.Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lRow, j)).Copy _
   Destination:=wsT.Range(Cells(LR, k), Cells(LR, k)).Offset(1, 0)
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` to see what error is being thrown.

Comment: Hello Portland Runner, I get `Method Range of object worksheet failed` and `wsS.Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lRow, j)).Copy _
   Destination:=wsT.Range(Cells(LR, k), Cells(LR, k)).Offset(1, 0)` is highlighted which I thought was the problem but I can not get what is wrong, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've slightly modified your code to be more reliable:

```
Sub MoveUnder()
    Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
    Dim ar, er, i, h, j, k
    Dim lRow As Long, LR As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set wsT = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    ar = Array("user id", "user name")    ' Find column to copy
    er = Array("user id", "user name")    ' Find column to paste beneith

    lRow = wsS.Range("A" & wsS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LR = wsT.Range("A" & wsT.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
        Set rng1 = wsS.Range("1:1").Find(ar(i), wsS.Cells(1, wsS.Columns.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows)
        Set rng2 = wsT.Range("1:1").Find(er(i), wsT.Cells(1, wsT.Columns.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            j = rng1.Column
            k = rng2.Column

            wsS.Range(wsS.Cells(2, j), wsS.Cells(lRow, j)).Copy _
                Destination:=wsT.Cells(LR + 1, k)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You should fully qualify your `Cells` objects like this: `wsT.Cells(LR, k)` and so on.

Also check this link for explanation [**Why I should use On Error Resume Next judiciously**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673529/if-not-function-proceeds-when-value-is-the-one-specified/21673617#21673617)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. simoco I notice that you have `Dim ar, er, i, h, j, k` these do not need specific Dims like `Dim ar As Variant` ?

Comment: By default all variables has type `Variant` untill you specify any other, so you can always ommit `As Variant` part in your declaration