# Much faster VBA Macro for Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a short VBA Macro to run several macros on different sheets. But it takes about 1 1/2 minute because it calls the macros in a row. It would be great if it could call them at once.:

```
Public Sub Gesamt_Rechner()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Application.EnableEvents = False

 On Error Resume Next

Sheets("Ra1").Select
Call Berechnen1
Sheets("Ra2").Select
Call Berechnen1
Sheets("Ra3").Select
Call Berechnen1
Sheets("Ra4").Select
Call Berechnen1
Sheets("Ra5").Select
Call Berechnen1
Sheets("Ra6").Select
```

...... and so on.

Is there a way to call them much faster? Or every at once :)

Berechnen1.:

```
Sub Berechnen1()

  Range("P26").ClearContents
  Range("I38").GoalSeek Goal:=32, ChangingCell:=Range("P26")

If Range("P26") < 0 Then
Range("P26") = Application.RoundUp(Range("P26"), 0)
Else
Range("P26") = Application.RoundDown(Range("P26"), 0)
End If

'Hier wird das Delta für den Reiter "E1" OHNE RUNDEN berechnet'
  Range("P91").ClearContents
  Range("I103").GoalSeek Goal:=32, ChangingCell:=Range("P91")

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) 2) [Why I should use On Error Resume Next judiciously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673529/if-not-function-proceeds-when-value-is-the-one-specified/21673617#21673617)

Comment: I use On Error Resume Next because the Sheets doesn't exist sometimes.

Comment: maybe this would be a good question on code review but here its off-topic as is too broad to answer and possibly primarily opinion based

Comment: **Post your code for Berechnen1.**

Comment: Berechnen1 Code added :)

Comment: Unless you check `Err` after every statement, `On Error Resume Next` means "ignore all errors" which is not a good idea.

Comment: Have you done any timings to discover which statements are taking an excessive amount of time?  `Select` is slow but I doubt it is that slow.  How many worksheets might not exist?  In my experience, the VBA error handler is slow; is that where the time is going.  Which worksheet is being processed by Berechnen1 when the `Select` fails?  Is that where the time is going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring an awful lot from hidden code base so I might way off.  Initially, I thought perhaps your code could well be tightened in terms of syntax so use

```
Sub Gesamt_Rechner()

    Dim l As Long
    For l = 1 To 6
        Sheets("Ra" + Chr$(48+l)).Select
        Call Berechnen1
    Next l

End Sub
```

instead of repeating lines.  Having said that, even after tightening your code I don't actually think that the problem is in the Excel VBA.  I should imagine that the time is taken in your goal-seeking and I am inferring that you have some financial model going on here, "Delta" is a mathematical sensitivity term frequently used in Investment Banks.  Your next step is to tighten the worksheet formulae.  After that if still slow you'll have to write the equivalent model in C++.

Comment: I think you mean `chr$(48+l)`.  However, I do not believe this loop would make any difference.  I believe your point about goal-seeking is much more relevant.

Comment: Yes, `chr$(48+l)`, quite right.  Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont't think that's possible, VBA executes everything line by line. If your execution is slow, just try to improve the code itself by increasing its efficiency if it is possible.

Comment: Specifically, vba is single threaded.